# Q: Ionic3 saving base64Image as image using cordova-base64-to-image plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, base64, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-camera-preview for taking pics and cordova-base64-to-gallery to save base64 string as picture.

Problem is it does not save my base64Image as image.

What I am doing now: after taking picure I am calling this:

```
this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(this.base64Image).then(
    res => this.toast.show('P -> Saved to gallery: ' + res, '5000', 'center').subscribe(),
    err => this.toast.show('P -> Error saving to gallery: ' + err , '7000', 'center').subscribe()
  );
```

where `this.base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;`
resulting with error as: `Error while saving image`

if i change `this.base64Image` as `this.base64Image = imageData;`
i am getting error as: `data.replace is not a function`,
data.replace is part of base64ToGallery.js from cordova-base64-to-gallery plugin.

I can display pic correctly as a preview using:

```
<img class="image-container" src="{{base64Image}}" />
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: If you log `this.base64Image` do you have your data inside ?

Comment: @Djiggy - yes I have also I can display it in preview in `<img` element of webpage.

Comment: Check if you have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Comment: @Djiggy in `plugin.xml` ot the cordova-base64-to-gallery there is this:
`<!-- android -->
  <platform name="android">
    <source-file src="src/android/Base64ToGallery.java" target-dir="src/it/nexxa/Base64ToGallery"/>

    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    </config-file>`
...where else should i check?

Comment: can you please tell me how did you get the image?

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala this is done almost out of the box, using cordova-camera-preview plugin, call `this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.pictureOpts).then((imageData)=>{
   this.base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
}`

then on .html call 

`<img class="image-container" src="{{base64Image}}" />`

Comment: Okk, The `imageData` Returns you a path of the image so you need to encode that file like this `this.base64.encodeFile(imagePath).then((base64String: string) => {
            // console.log("-----base64String-----" + base64String);`

Comment: @MustafaLokhandwala `imageData` returns actual data, not path. Btw, imagePath is not defined in my code as well as base64... i might be missing something in between from your example, can you put whole code here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this I needed to add permissions to write into storage within page which had code to save image.
In my case I placed below code inside constructor:

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
  result => console.log("Permissions granted", result.hasPermissions),
  error => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
);
this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using cordova-plugin-camera-preview for taking pics and cordova-base64-to-gallery to save base64 string as picture.

Problem is it does not save my base64Image as image.

What I am doing this :
**this.picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;**

replace this : 
**this.picture = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;**